# Не сворачивать activity?

Tags: android, java

Есть приложение. По определенному событию открывается activity. Как сделать так, чтобы пока пользователь не введет данное окно, его нельзя было не свернуть, не закрыть?

Comment: можно, если сделать системное модальное окно. Но это очень грубо по отношению к пользователю.

Comment: Если что-то нельзя свернуть, или закрыть, то это вирус. Я бы лично дал леща автору такого приложения...